# Doctrine update doesn't do anything

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to add a OneToMany bidirectional association on two tables: **Course** and **Certified**

There was already a OneToMany relation but Unidirectional.

So I modified both entities to make it bidirectional and added the property on the **course** side

Here are the two Entities:

```
/**
 * Course
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ME\ExamsBundle\Entity\CourseRepository")
 */
class Course    
{
 /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ME\ExamsBundle\Entity\Certified", mappedBy="course")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
  */
 private $certified;

//getters and setters...

}

/**
 * Certified
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ME\ExamsBundle\Entity\CertifiedRepository")
 */
class Certified
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ME\ExamsBundle\Entity\Course", inversedBy="certified")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $course;

// getters and setters...

}
```

But when i use the command

```
    doctrine:schema:update -- dump-sql
```

It tells me that there's nothing to update.

I tried to

- clear the metadata cach
- remove the nullable on both sides
- drop the database and recreate it

But the property **certified** never appeared in the course table in the database.

I'm kind of stuck here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Tom

Comment: try `doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bidirectional relation in Doctrine isn't different from a one-directional one from a SQL-point-of-view: that's because Doctrine can infer the inverse relation reversing the foreign key from the other table. Adding a new colum to your Course table would be a not normalized form, or worse it will have no sense.

The response of the Doctrine's command is all right.

Please study some more on normalized forms of databases: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: So it's normal that doctrine doesn't add anything to the tables, and when i try to access the certified property in course with the getter, doctrine will use the foreign key to get all the certified objects corresponding in the certified table. Am I correct ?